# How to support "town" and "city" when querying Nominatim?

Tags: python, dictionary, geojson

Reverse geocoding with Nominatim seems to return either "town" or "city" depending on the size of the location.

```
import geojson
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

location = "48.84837905, 2.28229522311902"
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my-application",timeout=3)
location = geolocator.reverse(location)
print(location.raw)
#Sometimes "town", sometimes "city"
##print(location.raw['address']['town'])
##print(location.raw['address']['city'])
```

What is a good way to handle both cases?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what `try-except` is for:

```
try:
    print(location.raw['address']['town'])
except KeyError:
    print(location.raw['address']['city'])
```

**Alternatives**

Some performance-aware people will say "but try-except is expensive".

You could use some other alternatives:

- `if 'town' in location.raw['address']: ... else: ...`
- `location.raw['address'].get('town', location.raw['address'].get('city'))`

Each approach has its own pluses and minuses. `.get`, for example, is not lazy. `location.raw['address'].get('city')` will 
   be evaluated before `'town'` is looked-up so as a matter of fact it is more 
   wasteful and counter-productive. 
The `if-else` approach (depending on how it is used) will probably need to hash one of the keys twice.

I think that putting the more common key in the `try` block will be good enough.

Let's do some tests:

```
from timeit import Timer
from random import choice

list_of_dicts = [{choice(('town', 'city')): 1} for _ in range(2000)]

def try_except():
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        try:
            d['town']
        except KeyError:
            d['city']

def if_else():
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        if 'town' in d:
            d['town']
        else:
            d['city']

def get():
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        d.get('town', d.get('city'))


print(min(Timer(try_except).repeat(10, 10)))
print(min(Timer(if_else).repeat(10, 10)))
print(min(Timer(get).repeat(10, 10)))
```

This outputs

```
0.0053282611981659705
0.0018278721105344786
0.00536558375274554
```

meaning that in this example of 2000 dictionaries, the `if-else` was the fastest (even though it needs to hash one of the keys twice), and `try-except` and `get` were about the same.